# Inheriting from multiple classes

Tags: python, oop

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1


class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.two = 2


class Three(One, Two):
    def __init__(self):
        self.three = 3
        super().__init__()


obj = Three()

print(obj.one)
print(obj.two)
print(obj.three)
```

i am currently self learning OOP, i am having a hard time understanding why the object was able to print the attribute from Class One but not also the one from Class Two despite me using the super function, the error raised is `AttributeError: 'Three' object has no attribute 'two'`. How do we inherit from multiple classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super().__init__()` in Three will only refer to the first class in Method Resolution Order. In order to call all the `__init__`, you'd need to do `super()` in all of them:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1
        super().__init__()


class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.two = 2
        super().__init__()
```

Or, if you don't want to / can't modify parent class signatures, you refer to the classes directly instead of using `super`, so they will all be called regardless of MRO:

```
class Three(One, Two):
    def __init__(self):
        self.three = 3
        One.__init__()
        Two.__init__()
```

Comment: Okay thank you i understand, if i may ask, what is the caveat of referring to the classes directly instead of using the super function?

Comment: @saleem I think one of the biggest issues is that when you want to change what classes Three inherits from, you need to change it in 2 different places.

Answer (score 0):

```
class One:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one = 1
        super().__init__()
class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.two = 2
        super().__init__()
class Three(One,Two):
    def __init__(self):
        self.three = 3
        super().__init__()
    


obj = Three()

print(obj.one)
print(obj.two)
print(obj.three)
```

use super().__init__method in every class.
if you dont want to use it. you can call init methods of class one and class two in init method of class three.